# How can I check my gmail and click all of the links in each email using selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, email, selenium

I have created a selenium script to login to gmail but I also want to click on each email and then click on every link in that email.

I'm using this to test my email support on one of my websites and I've got multiple emails and my site keeps getting flagged as spam when using IMAP so I need to use selenium.

the html for each email is in the tr tags.

```
<tbody>
   <tr id=":37" class="zA yO x7" aria-labelledby=":38" tabindex="-1">
   <tr id=":3h" class="zA yO" aria-labelledby=":3i" tabindex="-1">
   <tr id=":3r" class="zA yO" aria-labelledby=":3s" tabindex="-1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to python but I think this little bit of code should solve your problem you will just have to point towards a main word to click

```
    eleml = driver.find_element_by_link_text('@gmail.com')

    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(eleml,200,200)
    action.click()
    action.perform()
```

I put @gmail.com but I guess you could pinpoint it to .com and it would probably work for both email and the link in the email if you repeat the code, I hope this helps but like I said I'm a newbie to python so this might not be the best way.